# Add a checkbox on registration page for subscription newsletter with Simplenews

Tags: 7, emails, notifications

I'd like to add a checkbox for subscription to a newsletter on the user registration page.

I'm using [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created a Newsletter category, go to `admin/config/services/simplenews` and click on **edit newsletter category** next to your newsletter category.

You'll see subscription settings. Select "Default On" or "Default Off" to display a checkbox on user registration form.

see image below for detailed explanation of setting mentioned above
 [image]